# login using email and password from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session

i want to make users login with there email and password based on table on mysql
the database name is yandexd
the table of users is utilisateur
i have column Email, and another one MotDePass on utilisateur like is in the images I created a file name index.php with code bellow.

here is my index.php code I used but is not working

```html
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
 define('DB_SERVER',  'localhost');
 define('DB_USERNAME',  'root');
 define('DB_PASSWORD',  '');
 define('DB_DATABASE',  'yandexd');
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
$sql="SELECT idutilisateur FROM utilisateur WHERE Email='$username' and MotDePass='password'";
$result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
  $_SESSION['acces'] = "oui";
  $_SESSION['nom']   = $_POST['username'];
  $_SESSION['accueil']  = 0;
  $_SESSION['produit']   = 0;
        } else {
            echo "Réessayez ...";
            $_SESSION['acces'] = "non";
        }
} else if(isset($_POST['disconnect'])) {
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION);
}
?>
  <div id="pageintro" class="hoc clear"> 
<article>
   <?php
            if(!isset($_SESSION["acces"]) || $_SESSION["acces"] != "oui") {
        ?>
  <form method="post" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
   <fieldset >
   <legend>Login</legend>
   <input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>
    
   <label for='username' >Nom d'utilisateur:</label>
   <input type='text' name='username' id='username'  maxlength="50" />
    
   <label for='password' >Mot de Pass:</label>
   <input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" />
    
   <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Connecter' />
    
   </fieldset>
  </form>
        <?php
            } else {
        ?>
   <form method="post" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
   <fieldset>
    <legend>
     Se déconnecter !
    </legend>
    <input type="submit" name="disconnect" value="Se déconnecter"/>
   </fieldset>
  </form>

        <?php
            }
        ?>
</article>
```

my table is like in the picture

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check this line:

```
$sql="SELECT idutilisateur FROM utilisateur WHERE Email='$username' 
and MotDePass='password'"; //you mean $password??
```

N.B: maybe you missed `$` sign before `password` (`MotDePass='password'`) to work it as a variable..

Comment: @Bynd you can upvote or accept an answer if that works for you :) And let me know if you have any query regarding this question.

Comment: how to vote up 
I do but seems it still 0 i don't know how to do
it show this message
Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.